# How to fix/ remove the /dev/sdb1 partition: It will likely to fail soon

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk-space, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed Ubuntu as dual boot with Windows. Since then, I had no problems but for the last couple of days, I get error saying that disk is likely to fail soon. The problem is that, I cannot even find where is that disk and it says master boot record.

It is weird because I have used 32 GB USB to install Ubuntu but I had used 8GB one 5 years ago to try out. Is it safe to remove this disk?

The warning:

[image: Disks]

Partition, disk info:

```
    xxx-550P5C:~$ lsblk -f
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/bare
loop1
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/chro
loop2
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop3
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop4
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop5
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gimp
loop6
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gimp
loop7
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop8
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop9
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
loop10
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-
loop11
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gtk-
loop12
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/iced
loop13
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/oper
loop14
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/oper
loop15
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/pros
loop16
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/pych
loop17
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/snap
loop18
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/spot
loop19
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/snap
loop20
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/spot
loop21
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/vlc/
loop22
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/snap
loop23
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/core
loop24
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/snap
loop25
     squash                                                  0   100% /snap/gnom
sda                                                                   
├─sda1
│    ntfs   Windows RE tools
│                 EC162DF6162DC306                                    
├─sda2
│    vfat   SYSTEM
│                 3A2F-E9F2                             249,6M    16% /boot/efi
├─sda3
│                                                                     
├─sda4
│    ntfs         A08430F48430CE92                                    
├─sda5
│    ntfs   SAMSUNG_REC2
│                 A43490FC3490D322                                    
├─sda6
│    vfat   SAMSUNG_REC
│                 A232-2F92                                           
├─sda7
│    ext4         ffcee5f6-0e93-418c-a44d-7be741d6d59f    8,5G    57% /
├─sda8
│    swap         f2f0d96e-c989-4ca1-a17c-18dfb786afe0                [SWAP]
└─sda9
     ext4         129e3ed0-e9b4-430e-861c-24db1aef675e   76,8G     6% /home
sdb                                                                   
└─sdb1
                                                                      
sr0 

xxx-550P5C:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

Edit:

```
lsblk -S
NAME HCTL       TYPE VENDOR   MODEL                     REV TRAN
sda  0:0:0:0    disk ATA      ST1000LM024_HN-M101MBB   0002 sata
sdb  1:0:0:0    disk ATA      SanDisk_SSD_i100_8GB     6.04 sata
sr0  2:0:0:0    rom  TSSTcorp TSSTcorp_DVDWBD_SN-406AB SC00 sata

lsblk -f /dev/sdb
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                     
└─sdb1
```

As question clarification, I am not sure what to do so that I am not asking specific command. My question is that what are the best steps to proceed with this kind of problem. In other words, what to do with a 8 GB disk which is not mounted but every reboot shown as "will likely to fail soon" and labelled as MBR (please see the picture).

Comment: Why would it not be safe to remove it? It's not mounted or anything. But what do you mean by "you cannot find it"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you run `lsblk -S` and `lsblk -f /dev/sdb`?

Comment: Question editted, thanks for your comments!

Comment: Says it's connected via SATA, not via USB – check inside the computer?

Comment: Yes, indeed there is a small boot SSD inside the laptop. I believe reserved for fast booting of Windows OS. Do you think that something within Ubuntu or I did damaged this partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes, indeed there is a small boot SSD inside the laptop. I believe reserved for fast booting of Windows OS.

Then everything is working as intended: This SSD has one partition that does not contain any data that makes sense to Linux, so **do not** try something like `fsck` on it. The "Bad magic number in super-block" is exactly what is expected to happen.

I am not familiar with how Ubuntu produces the "disk is likely to fail soon" assessment. If it's just based on "cannot recognize partitions on this disk", you can ignore it.

To be on the safe side, check the SMART values with `sudo smartctl -A /dev/sdb`.

Comment: The message is in the screenshot, it's easy to miss it in the question.

Comment: The assessment is based on SMART attributes, e.g. bad sector count. Opening the "`⁝`" button _(the shashlik menu)_ would show an option to display the actual SMART data. (However, the gnome-disks app uses libatasmart which is rather out-of-date and doesn't know how to deal with SSDs at all, so it might be misinterpreting some of the attributes.)